# mysql query with join and group by

Tags: mysql, left-join

I working on my project using mysql database but when I trying to retrieve information from tow tables using left join statements ,  the data from first tables cannot be displayed and display null value even if the table has many data 
.
this is my query

```
SELECT
   hotspots.name,
   count(distinct(UserName)) as users,
   count(radacctid),
   avg(AcctSessionTime)as Avg,
   sum(AcctSessionTime) as allacctsession 
FROM
   radacct 
   left JOIN
      hotspots 
      ON (radacct.mac_address LIKE hotspots.mac) 
GROUP BY
   hotspots.name;
```

this is the result

```
+------+-------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
| name | users | count(radacctid) | Avg       | allacctsession |
+------+-------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
| NULL |     7 |               31 | 7433.6774 |         230444 |
+------+-------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

the name value has value in hotspots table but not displayed 
.
and when I make this query as right join , it displayed the name column and display null for aother columns

Comment: Your `LIKE` does not have any wildcard so it will only match exact unless `hotspots.mac` has the wildcard in it.  `ON (radacct.mac_address LIKE '%'+hotspots.mac+'%')`

Answer (score 0):

There are accounts for which there is no associated hotspot. 31 of them to be precise. Since the `hotspots` table is on the right hand side of the join, it will be NULL when there is no matching MAC address . Your query groups the NULL ones together and the calculates the aggregates that you see.

Perhaps you meant to have `hotspots` on the left side of the join?

```
SELECT hotspots.name,
       count(distinct(UserName)) as users,
       count(radacctid),
       avg(AcctSessionTime)as Avg,
       sum(AcctSessionTime) as allacctsession
FROM hotspots left JOIN radacct ON
    (radacct.mac_address LIKE hotspots.mac)
GROUP BY hotspots.name;
```

Comment: thank you for reply but now the  name column is displayed but other table's colums are hidden

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some sample data, but you should probably just use a standard (inner) join. Also, why are you using `LIKE` without a pattern? Please add some sample data to your question, and the expected output.